# Why does the TOR browser bundle disclose my location

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, deanonymization

All sites visited using the TOR browser bundle correctly identify the country from where I'm accessing the internet. Why is that and how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Tor, the system randomly selects an exit node. Given that some countries have more exit nodes than others, there are varying odds that your session will choose an exit node from your country of origin. If this is a concern you can reconnect to the network and get assigned a new random exit node.